# python NameError: name 'xxx' is not defined

Tags: python, undefined, nameerror

```
puzzle = [[' 1', ' 2', ' 3', ' 4'], [' 5', ' 6', ' 7', ' 8'],[ ' 9', '10', '11', '12'], ['13', '14', '15', ' X']]

def find_pos(alist, item):
    for i in alist:
        for j in range(4):
            if i[j] == item:
                row = alist.index(i)
                col = j

find_pos(puzzle,' X')

a = row
print(a)
```

I think I defined the name `row` by running the function `find_pos`, if not, how to fix it to get `row`

Do not put any print in the `find_pos` function

Comment: The variables created within a function do not end up in global scope after the function is called.

Comment: Python scope/block is defined by indentation...

Comment: Hello and welcome on stackoverflow. Please keep all code associated with the question, so there's no mess trying to read it.

Answer (score 4):

Just return the values from the function:

```
puzzle = [[' 1', ' 2', ' 3', ' 4'], [' 5', ' 6', ' 7', ' 8'],[ ' 9', '10', '11', '12'], ['13', '14', '15', ' X']]

def find_pos(alist, item):
    for i in alist:
        for j in range(4):
            if i[j] == item:
                row = alist.index(i)
                col = j
                return row, col

row, col = find_pos(puzzle,' X')

print(row)
```

Note that if the item isn't found, it will return `None` (because every function that doesn't return anything returns `None` by default), in which case the code will throw an error.

Comment: One comment: If I'm reading this right, the `return row, col` statement should be at the same indentation level as the `for`.  Otherwise it will do a return the first time through the lists where `i[j] == item`.

Comment: @DougR. I believe that is the indended effect: To find the first instance of where `i[j] == item`.

Comment: My apologies.  I missed that from the explanation and the sample code.